# I need to color cells by value in Python go.Table

Tags: python-3.x, heatmap

An example of the header and cell data are below. I need to create a table using "graph_objects.Table" that colors each cell by the cell value. However, I also need the first row NOT to be colored by value as it is a label as well as the column header. I have an Excel example below of what I would like the table to look like. Note that I have tried other options such as go.Heatmap and ff.create_annotated_heatmap, but neither of those seem to give the exact results I am looking for. Namely, a heatmap colored by cell value, with X and Y axis labels aligned with the rows/columns that I can include in a dash application.

Here are the example data and table:

```
wf_heat_header = ['Dose\Focus', -.2, 0, .2]
wf_heat = [[20, 22, 24],
           [500, 550, 500],
           [425, 490, 425],
           [400, 450, 400]]
```

[Excel heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFf2o.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my answer... details can be found here under the "Highlighting cells by value with a colorscale like a heatmap" header: https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).